# How to get git remote URL of the dokku app

Tags: git, configuration, ubuntu-16.04, dokku

I installed dokku on a pure Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS
My server's domain name is e.g. abc.def.com
I created a new app, e.g. blog

```
dokku apps:create blog
```

How can I get correct URL to set git remote

```
git remote add dokku <?>:blog
```

I tried the case based on the original docs

- git remote add dokku dokku@abc.def.com:blog

but I cannot reach the repo when I try to push

```
> git push dokku

fatal: 'blog' does not appear to be a git repository               
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  

Please make sure you have the correct access rights                
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try finding out what your dokku server has already assigned as a url to your app and use that, this you can do with the command `dokku domains:report`, or you could just set a domain for your newly created application by using the command `dokku domains:add blog example.com` on the dokku server, then `git remote add dokku <dokku-ssh-root>@example.com:blog` on your devbox.

As an example `git remote add dokku dokku@dokku.me:blog` on one's the devbox

I hope this helps. See the dokku [documentation](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration/domains/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @Lehlohonolo although the question is not relevant anymore and I cannot validate your answer.